# Flowtype: Cannot assign X to Y because property Y is missing in null

Tags: javascript, flowtype

A relatively simple problem, but one I keep bumping into in various forms.

Here's an example (test with [try-flow](https://flow.org/try/)):

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
    value: string | number 
}

export default class Example extends React.Component<Props> {
    _hiddenInput: { current: React.ElementRef<'input'> | null };
    value(val: number) {
        if (this._hiddenInput.current !== null) {
            this._hiddenInput.current.value = String(1234);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the `_hiddenInput.current` is a ["maybe-type"](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/maybe/#toc-refining-maybe-types) object property, which doesn't seem to get refined properly with the if-not-null check.

How would y'all solve this?

Comment: Your code should be posted **here** so that people can see it, both now in order to help you and later for others with a similar problem.

Comment: ^ Missing the link there @Pointy

Comment: The link is not enough. There's no guarantee that the external source will last. Please look over the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and in particular the "How to ask a question" explanations.

Comment: Oh my mistake, I thought you had a formatting mistake with **here**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Flow doesn't know what side-effects the `String` function might have, so the `this._hiddenInput.current !== null` refinement is invalidated when you call `String(1234)` (which happens before the assignment). Consider this contrived example:

```
export default class Example extends React.Component<Props> {
  _hiddenInput: { current: React.ElementRef<'input'> | null };
  value(val: number) {
    if (this._hiddenInput.current !== null) {
       this._hiddenInput.current.value = String(1234);
    }
  }
}

const example = new Example();
example._hiddenInput = { current: elementRef };

window.String = function(input) {
  example._hiddenInput.current = null;
  return `${input}`;
};
// Throws, because the String-function above will be called between
// refining the nullable type and assigning to it.
example.value(1)
```

You can either replace the function call with something that Flow knows doesn't have side-effects

```
this._hiddenInput.current.value = `${1234}`
```

or you can "secure" the container object into a local variable before assigning to its property

```
const {current} = this._hiddenInput
if (current !== null) {
  current.value = String(1234);
}
```

See [Refinement Invalidations](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations) in the docs.
Of course, the `String` function doesn't *actually* do anything like this, but currently Flow doesn't have any way of knowing that. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2715) for a way to mark functions as *pure*, which could help here some day.

Comment: Argh! I knew the answer would inevitably be as (relatively) simple as the question itself - It's just that Flow was pointing me somewhere completely different! Thanks so much.